# LED with opto-isolator does not work

Tags: opto-isolator

schematic_1

[image: schematic_1]

schematic_2

[image: schematic_2]

schematic_3

[image: schematic_3]

If I wired like schematic_1, L1 and L2 are lighting.
But, in schematic_2, L1 is not lighting even though L2 is lighting.
When I wired in series as schematic_3, L1 is lighting.

**Why L1 is not lighting in schematic_2 but L1 in schematic_1 is lighting?**

Comment: You need to get your hands on a cheap volt meter.  Measure the voltage drops in those circuits and I think you will understand.  (And then what Spehro says below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LED in the optocoupler is an infrared type rather than a visible type. As such, it has a much lower forward drop than even a red LED, so when the two are in parallel, the IR LED in the optocoupler hogs all the current and has a forward voltage drop of perhaps 1.1 or 1.2V, which is not enough to allow the visible LED to light.

When two similar visible LEDs are in parallel, they share current better, and will typically light to (visually) similar brightness. When the two LEDs are in series (and there is enough voltage for both) then the same current flows through both LEDs and both will light.

Here is what typical curves look like (this one for a [Lite-on 4N35 optocoupler](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-99-0012/S_110_4N35%20%204N37%20(%20M,%20S,%20S-TA1%20)%20(Rev.pdf))

[image]

This one for [Cree LEDs](http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/HB/Data%20Sheets/C5SMF%20C5SME%20RJS%20GJS%20BJS%20201.pdf) of various colors :

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'd like to know if it is possible in schematic_2, share similar amount of current between L1 and U1 so to make L1 gets light. Can I?

Comment: Sure, just use two resistors rather than one (each LED gets its own resistor) and calculate the resistor values so that the currents are the same (the optocoupler will have a higher value resistor since it has less forward voltage).